# CDF/ ECDF plot for data with two attributes

Tags: probability, python, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a data in the following format:

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\textbf{colm_1} & \textbf{colm_2}\\
3 & 1\\
10 & 0\\
3 & 0\\
100 & 1\\
. & .\\
. & .
\end{array}
$$

*colm_1* are basically whole numbers and *colm_2* denotes binary values say success or failure. What I am expecting is that, for lower values of attributes in *column_1* the probability of success will be less, while as the values of *column_1* increases, the probability of success escalates.

Now, how can I plot the CDF (or ECDF) of the above data?. From my perspective it should basically say *P(success | colm_1 = **Value**) <= Some Number between 0-1*. Where **Value** is any whole number in *colm_1*. I hope I am clear in my explanation, if not please rectify me.

Finally, I mainly use python's numpy and scipy. How can I transform my data so that I can plot the ecdf?

Comment: This question may confuse people because it does not actually ask for a CDF. It could be understood as asking how to estimate the *conditional* CDF of success. A standard procedure for constructing such an estimate is logistic regression. It requires additional assumptions concerning how the conditional mean might be related to the values in column 1. You can find out a great deal about logistic regression on this site by [searching it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic+regression?sort=votes&pageSize=30).

Comment: @whuber. Thanks for the reply; however, I am not doing any classification here so I don't need any regression analysis. I just need a simple the CDF. To be specific, by calculating P(success| colm_1=3) say if I get 0.2. but I don't want this "exact value" (ie 0.2) . Instead, I want P(success| colm_1=3) <= Some_value (between 0 and 1 obviously).

Comment: You are not asking for a "simple CDF": you are asking for *one CDF for every possible value in column 1.*  (It's possible you *mean* something else, but that's what you're asking.)  The only way to avoid regression is to make sure you have multiple cases for every value in column 1.